# calculate location in virtual radar by gps position and compass

Tags: math

so i got three variables, my location, my target location and the compass heading.
how can i calculate where the target location should be represented on a virtual radar?

i guess i first must calculate the distance between the two gps points and the angle of them relative to north or so. and then there should be a formula with sin or cos to place that point on a coordinate system...?

ps: in javascript...

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of coordinate transformations?

Comment: What should be in the straight-up direction? North? "Compass heading"? Target? Hopefully this question makes sense. First you need to elaborate on the "specs".

Comment: Would you want to use a fixed scale? If you have just two points, with one being your position, scaling would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Start with simpler problems.

1. In 2D, try converting back and forth between cartesian and polar coordinates. [References are available](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates).

   Do the same, but for the polar coordinates use an observer who measures angles from some ray that is *not* in the X direction.

   The same, but using an origin for the polar coordinates that is not at {x=0,y=0}.

   In 3D, go back and forth between cartesian and spherical coordinates.

   Again, with spherical coordinates in an arbitrary orientation, using an arbitrary origin.

   Now convert from GPS coordinates (which are spherical) to cartesian, then to radar-centered spherical.

Comment: maybe its possible to do it without coordinate transformations. i now implemented a coordinate system on top of my radar, setPoint(0, 0) draws the point to the center, setPoint(-100, -100) draws on the left bottom, etc. i also managed to calculate the azimuth and distance of my two points. now is in theory the following possible?: i add the azimuth to my heading and and transform it to deg and make a function out of it. now my point on the radar is the position on that function where the distance to (0, 0) is the (scaled) distance of my two gps points. thanks!

Comment: @blab, I can't make any sense out of that. Whatever it is, if it works then it's a coordinate transformation. *A coordinate transformation is what you're trying to achieve.*